# C# - Replace a character with nothing

Tags: c#, replace, richtextbox

I have a `RichTextBox` that looks like this:

```
TEXT  NEXT_TEXT  10.505   -174.994 0
TEXT  NEXT_TEXT  100.005  174.994  90 
TEXT  NEXT_TEXT  -10.000  -5.555   180
TEXT  NEXT_TEXT  -500.987 5.123    270
TEXT  NEXT_TEXT  987.123  1.000    180
TEXT  NEXT_TEXT  234.567  200.999  90
```

and I want to replace the **"."** with nothing and place it into a `ListBox`...

So the new file would look like this:

```
TEXT  NEXT_TEXT  10505   -174994 0
TEXT  NEXT_TEXT  100005  174994  90 
TEXT  NEXT_TEXT  -10000  -5555   180
TEXT  NEXT_TEXT  -500987 5123    270
TEXT  NEXT_TEXT  987123  1000    180
TEXT  NEXT_TEXT  234567  200999  90
```

I thought about multiplying the values by 1000 but I do not know how to properly do match calculations on a string.

So the next thought was to do this ***(HOWEVER THIS DOES NOT WORK)***:

```
  // Splits the lines in the rich text boxes
  string[] listOneLines = oneRichTextBox.Text.Split('\n');

  // Set the selection mode to multiple and extended.
  placementOneListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;

  // Shutdown the painting of the ListBox as items are added.
  placementOneListBox.BeginUpdate();

  // Display the items in the listbox.
  foreach (var item in listOneLines)
  {
      item.Replace(".","");
      placementOneListBox.Items.Add(item);
  }

  // Allow the ListBox to repaint and display the new items.
  placementOneListBox.EndUpdate();
```

---

- Can anyone help me figure out how to replace a "."?

Comment: string temp = text.Replace(".", "");
where text is the whole text from RTB

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Strings are immutable so this line is wrong:

```
item.Replace(".","");
```

This returns the string after the replacement has been made, but `item` is unchanged.  You need this:

```
foreach (var item in listOneLines)
    placementOneListBox.Items.Add(item.Replace(".",""));
```

Comment: Thank you! That is what I needed and it is the shortest way to do it!

Comment: I had to wait a couple more minutes :) Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 5):

```
string item2 = item.Replace(".", "");
```

You need to use the result of `Replace`, it doesn't operate on the string itself.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of the "" use String.Empty.
In this way there is no new object created.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
item.Replace(".", "");
```

Try this:

<s>item = item.Replace(".", "");</s> (edit: this was my original idea, but it's wrong)

```
placementOneListBox.Items.Add(item.Replace(".", ""));
```

Comment: Close, but I found out you actually need a new string item in order to replace it *(doing it the way you have shown here anyway)*

Comment: Oops! Good catch.You could also do: placementOneListBox.Items.Add(item.Replace(".","");

Comment: You can't assign to a `foreach` loop variable.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable, so

```
item.Replace(".","")
```

does not modify item, but returns a new string.

You need to use:

```
placementOneListBox.Items.Add(item.Replace(".",""));
```

Edit: and as you can see from the flurry of simultaneous responses, many of our peers agree! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your replace:

```
item.Replace(".","");
```

with this:

```
item = item.Replace(".","");
```

Comment: You can't assign to a `foreach` loop variable.

Answer (score 0):

How about

// Splits the lines in the rich text boxes
  string[] listOneLines = oneRichTextBox.Text.Replace(".","").Split('\n');